# Angular 2+: API Calls to populate <select> and set selected value

Tags: angular, api, chaining, flatmap

Let's say I have two REST API endpoints as follows:

To load a lookup list (e.g. Locations): host/api/locations 
to load user details: host/api/user/1

I will be displaying this information on a HTML form, which has a  to load the location list. When the user details is loaded, the  default selected value should be set to user's home location which is part of user details.

I know I can do this by chaining, either using subscribe method or [using flatmap in RxJs](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs). But both of them are actually for when the second API call is dependent on the response of the first. In my case, there's no dependency between the two API calls, the only glitch is that the locations should be loaded in the  for the user's home location to be set as the selected value.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, rxjs **forkJoin** operator comes for your help. It makes sure to emit values when response from all observables have arrived. Here is a descriptin from rxjs site

> One common use case for this is if you wish to issue multiple requests on page load (or some other event) and only want to take action when a response has been received for all. ([detailed link](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin))

Your implementation shall be something like this

```js
      let req1$ = this.apiService.api1(); //first observable
      let req2$ = this.apiService.api2(); //second observable
      
      forkJoin(req1$, req2$).subscribe(([response1, response2])=>{
      //Your implementation shall go here.
      });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I need. Just one thing - here the apiService returns observales right?

Comment: yes exactly. Also please note rxjs coding style, if variable name ends with dollar sign ($) it implicityly means this is an observable :-)

Answer (score 1):

ForkJoin will serve your purpose.

**‘forkJoin’** is the easiest way, when you need to wait for multiple HTTP requests to be resolved.

**‘forkJoin’** waits for each HTTP request to complete and group’s all the observables returned by each HTTP call into a single observable array and finally return that observable array.

```
const locations = this.http.get('host/api/locations');
const user = this.http.get('host/api/user/1');

forJoin(locations,user).subscribe(result => {
result[0]; // location
result[1]; // user
})
```